# Word: Prevent indentation for first paragraph on page

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

In Microsoft Word, I have configured the first line of every paragraph to be indented. I want to prevent this for paragraphs that are the first paragraph after a header, and prevent it for paragraphs that are the first paragraph on a page.

For example:

```
Header

Text of the first paragraph. Text of the first paragraph.
Text of the first paragraph. Text of the first paragraph. 
Text of the first paragraph. Text of the first paragraph.
(---- paragraph break here -------)
  Text of the second paragraph. Text of the second paragraph. 
Text of the second paragraph. Text of the second paragraph. 
Text of the second paragraph. Text of the second paragraph. 
(---- paragraph break here ------)
(soft page break here)
Text of the third paragraph. Text of the third paragraph. 
Text of the third paragraph. Text of the third paragraph.
```

Removing the indentation of paragraphs after headers can be done by hand, since these won't change much. But removing indentation on new pages is a lot more painful: every edit may change the page structuring and move paragraphs to a previous or next page.

So is there a way to configure Word that it applies special formatting to paragraphs that happen to be the first complete paragraph on a page with no partial paragraph preceding it?

Comment: Do you know about Styles, namely - Paragraph styles? I don't use Word a lot of years and can't recall, which conditions can be applied in style definitions

Comment: I don't know of any conditional styling in Word